# Coloring curved arrows in Xy-pic

Tags: color, xy-pic

I have created a recalcitrant object in Xy-pic. The intention was to color two curved arrows, but the expected code does not quite accomplish this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
    \xymatrix@R=1.25em@C=0em{
        &\ \  
        &s\ \ \  
            \ar@{-}@<-5pt> `d[r] `r [drrrrr]
        &\ \ \ 
        &\mathllap{s^{-1}\mspace{-2mu}}\mathrlap{\colon}
            \ar@[LimeGreen]@{-}@<-3pt> `d[r] `r [drrrrr]
        &\ 
        &a'
            \ar@{-}@<-2pt>[d]
        &s^{-1}
            \ar@[LimeGreen]@{-}@/^/@<-2pt>[d]
        &a_1
            \ar@{-}[d]
        &b' \ar@{-}@/^/[d]
        &[b_{(1)}]
        \\
        &\ \  
        &
        &
        &
        &\
        &\smash{a'}{\vphantom{t}}
        &s\smash{s^{-1}}
        &a_{\smash{1}}
        &s^{-1} \smash{b'}
        &[b_{(1)}]
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

yields the following:

[image: curved parts uncolored]

The curved bends in the arrow with the horizontal portion go uncolored, whereas the entire curved vertical arrow does get colored. I don't understand Xy-pic well enough to know what is going wrong, but I would like to do one of the following two things:

(1) color the entirety of both arrows;

(2) color only the portion of the arrows within a fixed small radius (say 1 en) of the intersection to visually highlight the crossing.

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: You're probably much better of switching to `tikz-cd` instead of `xy`, given that `xy` haven't gotten any updates since 2013

Comment: @daleif It is true...:-) but I like xy package. Why there is not updates since 2013? Best regards.